# Clear Figure in Loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

Clear figure in loop

Hi all,
I wanted to plot the evolution of histograms on a figure and clear it in every iteration before I load the new one.

```
for k in range(0,2):
     plt.hist(x(k))
     plt.show()
     plt.clf()
```

However, this doesn’t do it. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For example, if I execute this code: `t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
x = np.sin(t)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, x)
plt.show()
plt.clf()` It doesn't clear the figure, it just plots sin(t) on Figure 1. I wanted it to clear sin(t) at the end of this routine.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax seems to be incorrect

```
for k in range(0,2):
     plt.hist(x[k])
     plt.show()
     plt.clf()
```

to index into a list in python use `[]` not `()`

Comment: Thanks for this. However, the output still not correct. It should show me only the last figure since it supposes to clear the previous ones. I, however, get all figures at end of the loop.